# What's the simplest software to install to allow flexible Windows logins to our Windows 2012 R2 server?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I am the 'accidental admin' for a small but growing charity.  We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running on a single, newish server plus 8 workstations - 6 with Windows 7 Pro and 2 with Windows 10. The single server is simply a file server & not a domain controller.  Each user has a simple setup, they are users on the server and have shares that they access as  mapped network drives.  However with a growth in volunteers I'm being asked to setup the same user on several PCs, so the volunteers have a choice of PCs.  What is needed is to upgrade the server software so that users can logon at any PC and access their shares wherever they are.  To do this, I guess I need Active Directory installed?  My question is: What's the minimum I need to install on the server to make this happen? - and there's a supplementary question of what software needs to be added (if any) to the client PCs? I'm guessing I need to need to make the server a DC and then add AD, but I would value some firmer and more specific information. Are there other ways to achieve this?  I want to keep things as simple as possible, of course.  Thanks, and sorry if to some people this is a really dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2` then it can already be turned into a Domain Controller (DC) but you'll need to make sure you have the right licenses to make its use legal.

For what you are wanting to do (i.e. have staff be able to log in at any computer and the shared drives follow them around) then all the computers they will be logging in to will need to have (at least) the "Pro" versions of Windows (Windows 7 Pro, Windows 8 Pro, Windows 10 Pro) as these are the minimum versions that can be joined to a domain.

Having a domain will allow users to log on to any computer on the domain using a single username and password and you can configure things like shared drives, printers and many other settings from one central place (the server) and all the client computers will inherit these settings and everything just works.

The most frequently used license types are "User CALs" as they offer the most flexibility (one user license but the server can have multiple devices for one user and still be covered). Ideally if you have no idea what you're doing then professional assistance should be sought.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So I won't need to add any software to the client PCs? They will automagically detect a domain connection?  I have the necessary number of device CALs, by the way.

Comment: You will need to do some re-configuration of your LAN because there are some "best practises" when a network has a Windows Server DC - these are for the proper functionality of DHCP and (most importantly) DNS. You will need to configure the server with the roles you'll require. You'll then need to add the clients to the domain (easiest step TBH) and configuring  your shared folders, users and Group Policies. It's not an easy job but once it's done you'll wish you'd have done it sooner.